# Crash with message "outlined init with take of any protocol"

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, crash

I have the following very simple code:

```
protocol Delegate<T> {
    associatedtype T
    
    func f(t: T)
}

class ConcreteClass: Delegate {
    func f(t: Int) { }
}

class A<T> {

    private let delegate: any Delegate<T>
    
    init(delegate: any Delegate<T>) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
}

let a = A(delegate: ConcreteClass())
```

If it runs in Debug mode and everything is fine. However if run in release or `Optimization Level` of `Swift Compiler - Code Generation` is `Optimize for Speed [-O]` then it crashes with the following:

```
#0  0x0000000100003b49 in outlined init with take of any Delegate<Self.Delegate.T == Int> ()
#1  0x0000000100003ac4 in specialized A.init(delegate:) [inlined] at /Users/plamen/Projects/Tests/TestCrash2/TestCrash2/main.swift:25
#2  0x0000000100003ab7 in specialized A.__allocating_init(delegate:) [inlined] at /Users/plamen/Projects/Tests/TestCrash2/TestCrash2/main.swift:24
#3  0x0000000100003a96 in main at /Users/plamen/Projects/Tests/TestCrash2/TestCrash2/main.swift:29
#4  0x000000010001952e in start ()
```

[image: Crash]

Any ideas why? Is it bug in the optimiser?

Comment: Probably a bug. The optimiser should not break working code.

Comment: how this can be a working code? Starting from: `protocol Delegate<T>` - it's not even a proper syntax, you can only define generics as `associatedType` in protocol...

Comment: @khjfquantumjj - it is a new feature in Swift 5.7

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is a bug in Swift. I've reported it so will keep track on the progress

https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/61403